# Plotly.js: lock y-axis to avoid negative values

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I'm using Plotly.js to plot some data that I already know cannot be negative. I need to keep the zoom and other plot "navigation" features of Plotly, yet I would disallow the user to go below the zero on the y-axis, as it does not make sense for the type of data being plotted.

Ideally, I would like to allow the zoom only in the range `[0, 100]`, if possible.

I went through the documentation and github issues to find some ideas, so I'm not sure what I need is possible with the current release of Plotly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think a very similar, if not the same feature has been requested on the github page: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/887 however I don't see any implementation as of Dec. 17, 2020

Answer (score 8):

Set `layout.yaxis.rangemode: 'tozero'`

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: this short answer does not answer anything. Cause the question has not included any type of code to inject in. So, your answer doesn't mean anything. Please, provide a full answer so the community would have many benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this to set `yaxis` range

```
var layout = {
  yaxis:{
    range:[0,100]
  }
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/mdnasirfardoush/pen/qKNmOR)

Comment: I already tried that. It set an initial limit, but I'm still able to move way beyond the limits.